# Install GD Library for PHP in GoDaddy VPS with CentOS???

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, gd

When I tried to install php-gd library in my GoDaddy VPS with CentOS, It gives:

```
$ yum install php-gd
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
addons                                                    | 951 B     00:00
base                                                      | 2.1 kB     00:00
extras                                                    | 2.1 kB     00:00
update                                                    | 1.9 kB     00:00
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Install Process
No package php-gd available.
Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 1):

First, check if the package wasn't excluded. Open up the yum config with `vi /etc/yum.conf` and look for a line starting with `exclude=`if `php-gd`or `php*`is mentioned, remove it.

Sometimes VPS-hosters won't allow you to use some packages because they hog memory. So you might want to check you aliases by running `alias`and check if there is no alias for `yum`with an exclude-option.

Otherwise you could use RPMForge to install this package:

```
wget http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm
rpm -Uhv rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm
yum update && yum install php-gd
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the command that failed:

```
yum --exclude=kernel* -y install gettext automake19 libpng-devel openssl libpng-dev zlib-devel autoconf261 libidn-devel gmake libidn libXpm openssl-devel automake coreutils patch libstdc++-dev libltdl3-devel libltdl libopenssl0.9.7-static-devel libtool-ltdl-devel libXpm-devel sed libXpm-dev lsof krb5-dev flex glibc-dev expat-dev krb5-devel xorg-x11-devel libtool-ltdl libssl-dev pam-devel libopenssl0-devel zlib1-devel expat-devel libopenssl0-dev glibc-devel expat gcc-c++ zlib libstdc++ bison libstdc++-devel libjpeg-devel libtool-libltdl-devel libtool openssl-dev libopenssl0 libz-devel libjpeg-dev pam-dev fileutils libltdl-devel libopenssl0.9.7-devel e2fsprogs-devel ca_root_nss make libX11-devel libstdc++-devel.x86_64 gd cpp xorg-x11-dev gcc ssl-dev autoconf lex
```

> Since EasyApache was unable to resolve it automatically you should:
>          1) Manually run the failed YUM command (shown above) via SSH
>          2) See if your particular error is addressed at http://www.cpanel.net/support/could_not_ensurepkgs.htm
>          3) Resolve the YUM problem manually
>          4) Re-run EasyApache

When running that command as suggested by the output
above, you would see openssl conflicts between the i386 and
i686 packages:

**Transaction Check Error:**
 package openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7.i686 is already installed
 file /lib/.libcrypto.so.0.9.8e.hmac from install of openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7.i686 conflicts with file from package openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7.i386
 file /lib/.libssl.so.0.9.8e.hmac from install of openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7.i686 conflicts with file from package openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7.i386
 file /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8e from install of openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7.i686 conflicts with file from package openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7.i386
 file /lib/libssl.so.0.9.8e from install of openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7.i686 conflicts with file from package openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7.i386
 file /usr/bin/openssl from install of openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7.i686 conflicts with file from package openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7.i386
 file /usr/lib/openssl/engines/lib4758cca.so from install of openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7.i686 conflicts with file from package ( ... )

To fix this for you, I ran this command:

```
# rpm -e --nodeps --justdb openssl.i386
```

Next, I ran the yum command again, and it was successful.

Finally, I ran `/scripts/easyapache`, and it is running now. When
complete, there will be support for the gd php module.

Answer (score 0):

its definitely a package in Centos 5.5

is this vps cpanel? if so you have to install the gd library from the easyapache installer available in whm because by default on cpanel it disables php packages from being installed as it will break cpanel or parts of it

Answer (score -1):

EasyApache on WHM only installs Zlib under GD. No info about how to install GD2 [for image manipulation for CodeIgnitor v2.0] in goDaddy Linux VPS cpanel